# How to keep two images side by side when browser resizes?

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I am having a bit of trouble. I have two images side by side, and I’d like them to always stay on the same line side by side when my browser window resizes (shrinks).

What happens is that at one point one of the images is pushed down. I have put the two images in a `<figure>` and set the figure with a `max-width` but that didn’t work. Any help please?

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/srebne/ru9fmudr/

All the code in one snippet:

```css
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li.active a {
  border: 2px solid #dad9d8;
}
nav {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.3em;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffae00;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
  border: 2px outset #dad9d8;
  font-family: Andika, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
}
body {
  font-family: Rockwell, “Courier Bold”, Courier, Georgia, Times, “Times New Roman”, serif;
}
html {
  background: url(babybluebackgroundwallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  /*background-color: #D6EBFF*/
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #D6AD33;
  font-size: 40px;
}
#imgbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#logoimg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
#dkpic,
#srpic {
  border: solid 3px #D6AD33;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.teampic1 {
  float: left;
  max-width: 45%;
}
.teampic2 {
  float: right;
  max-width: 45%;
}
#aboutus {
  font-size: 30px;
}
#ourteam {
  font-size: 30px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  #philo {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
  }
  #team {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .teampic1 {
    max-width: 30%;
  }
  .teampic2 {
    max-width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="About Us">
  <title>FoodList About Us</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="imgbox">
    <img id="logoimg" src="logo.jpg" alt="foodlist logo">
  </div>
  <br>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="philo">
    <h2>Our Philosophy</h2>
    <p id="aboutus">At FoodList our mission is simple. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
  </div>
  <div id="team">
    <h2>Meet Our Team</h2>
    <figure class="teampic1">
      <img id="dkpic" src="davidko.jpg" alt="dk's picture">
      <figcaption>Dvzzn Xi</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="teampic2">
      <img id="srpic" src="srebne.png" alt="s's picture">
      <figcaption>Sgfkfk Rkesn</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p id="ourteam"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which two images? Have you tried setting `min-width`?

Comment: dkpic and srpic, and no I haven't what do I need to set min-width to? If you click the jfiddle and resize width down a bit you will see the images go from side by side to being one on top left and one on bottom right

Answer (score 2):

Use this styling on both figure elements:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 45%;
margin: 1%; //or more just play with it a little
vertical-align: top;
```

This should do

edit:
check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ru9fmudr/4/

The browser automatically sets a start-margin and end-margin etc to like 40px that's why when you scale down 45% width * 2 = 90% and the browser margin would be much more than 10% that's why it didn't work.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you are trying and keep things clean is the following:

CSS

```css
.line {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.line figure {
     width: 45%;
     margin: 0;
     display: inline-block;
}
.line figure:first-child {
     margin-right: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="team">
     <h2>Meet Our Team</h2>

    <div class="line">
        <figure>
            <img id="dkpic" src="davidko.jpg" alt="dk's picture">
            <figcaption>Dvzzn Xi</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img id="srpic" src="srebne.png" alt="s's picture">
            <figcaption>Sgfkfk Rkesn</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <p id="ourteam"></p>
</div>
```

To every new line with two pictures, open a new div class line. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap class for image class="img-responsive"

```
<img class="img-responsive" align="right" width="600" height="300" src="~/Images/someimage.jpg" alt="some text" hspace="25" vspace="25" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ultimate goal you are trying to accomplish is having two  elements sit side by side you need to set an exact width. Currently in your code the .teampic1 and .teampic2 classes have a max-width of 45%. This means that they can (and will) shrink smaller than 45% if they are forced to a size that is less than 45% of the parent element.

Replacing max-width 45% with a width 45% will correct the current situation.

There are additional potential issues you are running into without properly clearing floated elements but that is another issue entirely.